# CoreData With iCloud, Not working with sync Notification

Tags: swift, core-data, notifications, synchronization, icloud

I'm developing coredata with icloud.
i have problem with this.
coredata with icloud works fine  except sync notification~
my code here~

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, 
    selector: "changedDataOniCloud:", 
    name: NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification, 
    object: nil)
```

and suppose to receive sync notification with below,

```
func changedDataOniCloud(notification: NSNotification) {
    self.textView.text = "changedDataOniCloud"
}
```

I have iPhone and iPad.
if changed data in iphone, then ipad get sync data and changes notification have to responds. 
sync data works fine, but notification not working!

please check my project in github 
https://github.com/beauspiring/ios/blob/coredata_icloud/Example/ViewController.swift
(branch: coredata_icloud)

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem.

this is a good reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/UsingCoreDataWithiCloudPG/UsingSQLiteStoragewithiCloud/UsingSQLiteStoragewithiCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013491-CH3-SW3

I changed addObserver code here~

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(
    NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification, 
    object: self.moc.persistentStoreCoordinator, 
    queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), 
    usingBlock: { (noti: NSNotification) -> Void in
            self.textView.text = "Ubiquitous Content Changes"
})
```

Two parameters that object and queue are important
thank's my self :)